# What database to use for the following scenario?

Tags: database, performance, database-design, model, flexibility

I have the following problem that I need to solve for efficient querying, and flexible properties expansion:

nodes:

```
node_id1 
node_id2
node_id3
node_id4
node_id5
```

groups:

```
node_id1;node_id2;node_id3
node_id4;node_id5
```

`node_id1 < node_id2 < node_id3   => node_id1;node_id2;node_id3` (unique group ID from smallest to largest)

properties:

```
node_id1: color:red
node_id2: color:blue
node_id3: color:blue
```

results in:

```
node_id1;node_id2;node_id3: color:red:1,blue:2 size:3 ... etc
```

relation type:

```
node_id -IS_IN -> group
```

operations needed for speed optimization:

```
get groups by group properties, ex: color restrictions, min/max size, etc   
get all groups for given node_id    
update group properties when contained node_id property gets modified (can this be implemented in a smart way without too many lines of code?)
```

what kind of database would you recommend?
mysql, neo4j, arangodb, mongodb, others?

Answer (score 0):

First of all those aren't databases they are relational database management systems (RDBMS). They are two very different things because a database is a database is a database, but RDBMS's are very different from each other. So any RDBMS will work for you because they are all fundamentally the same. Personally I prefer to use SQL Server, Oracle, or MySQL as my RDBMS but they are all good.

Comment: The systems he lists are not all relational.

Comment: A few I wasn't familiar with in that case I would recommend using an RDBMS.